# CSS positioning issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, fixed

Just wanted your help on a CSS Positioning issue. Here is the link to the code on code pen... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FKdLq

When you click on 'Latest News' the text slides in and out, however the actual button itself stays static. What I would like is for the 'Latest News' button to slide with the text when clicked but cannot figure it out :|

The whole thing needs to be fixed to the browser window on the right.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am extremely new to jQuery, is my jQuery code 'clean'? ;)

Comment: Could you please place the relevant code on Stackoverflow? This will make most people more willing to answer and makes the question independent of codepen, otherwise the question is worthless if codepen goes offline/deletes your code.

Comment: Make use of `$(this)` in the toggle function and position it correctly

Comment: Sorry I thought seeing live code would be more useful. I have seen others on here use jsfiddle. Will do both in future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you're animating the "button" (defined by an `h2`, I believe) as well. It can be referenced by `this` in your function, since it's what's being clicked. Here's a fixed version of your JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("aside h2").toggle(function(){
            $('.box').animate({ right:"-350"});
            $(this).animate({right:"0"});
        },function(){
            $('.box').animate({ right:"-5"});
            $(this).animate({right:"271"});
    });
});
```

Hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: Yes that is perfect. Thank you!!

That is spot on. I foolishly was thinking about the child-parent element but of course the latest news button was not a child, so your right, they both need to be animated.


I have just done some messing about here made the button the child element, and of course, it now works that way also... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dapms


Only problem with this though is I can't see why z-index isn't working on the button, so it is behind the grey .box and drop shadow.


Do you see why thats not working? The main problem is already fixed, this is just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Adam Do the following: removing the `z-index` rule from `.box` (yes, completely). And then change the `z-index: 1;` in `.label` to `z-index: -1`. That should fix it. By the way, if this answer was useful to you, don't forget to "accept" it!

Comment: yes i tried that originally, and it seems to work initially, however when you close the tab and try to reopen the tab, it does not open, which I find very strange. Anyway, I have accepted, thanks again!

Comment: @Adam Add in `z-index: -100;` to `#news` (after doing the above steps). It should work now.